# Compute dot product of two dictionaries with tuple values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have two dictionaries that look like so:

```
dict_of_items = tf_idf_by_doc {1: [('dog', 3), ('bird', 0)], 2: [('egret', 2), ('cat', 3), ('bird', 0), ('aardvark', 1)], 3: [('fish', 6), ('bird', 0), ('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 5)], 4: [('fish', 6), ('bird', 0), ('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 2)], 5: [('egret', 4), ('bird', 0)], 6: [('bird', 0)], 7: [('dog', 5), ('bird', 0)], 8: [('bird', 0), ('aardvark', 1)]}

dict_of_search = {1: [('bird', 0), ('dog', 1), ('cat', 3)]}
```

I need to compute the dot product between the `dict_of_search` and *each of the keys* in the `dict_of_items`, and then store the resulting dot product values and keep track by key. What I mean is...

In `dict_of_items`, 1 and the item in `dict_of_search` have a vectors of:

```
|      | dict_of_items_1 | dict_of_search |
|:----:|:---------------:|:--------------:|
| bird |        0        |        0       |
|  dog |        3        |        1       |
|  cat |        0        |        3       |
```

And so my dot product would be: `3`

**Desired results would be a dictionary of keys in dict_of_items and their respective dot products as compared to dict_of_search (this will only ever be one item), sorted in descending order by dot product.**

However, I am not sure how to translate the shape of my dictionaries into two arrays to perform a vector calculation, especially when to handle when one of the terms does not appear (for example, in the example above `cat` did not appear in key `1` in `dict_of_items_1`.

I have tried something like this using `numpy`...

```
import numpy as numpy

def main():
    test_arr_1 = [1,2,3]
    test_arr_2 = [3,2,6]

    first_dot_product = numpy.dot(test_arr_1, test_arr_2)

    print("First Example: ", first_dot_product)

    test_arr_3 = [3,0,1]
    test_arr_4 = [2,10]

    second_dot_product = numpy.dot(test_arr_3, test_arr_4)

    print("Second Example Missing Value: ", second_dot_product)

main()
```

But that fails since the vectors are not of the same size and shape.

```
ValueError: shapes (3,) and (2,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 2 (dim 0)
```

I have also tried to reshape the dictionary values into lists:

```
def main():
    dict_of_items = {'1': [('bird', 0), ('dog', 3), ('egret', 2), ('bird', 0), ('aardvark', 1), ('cat', 3), ('dog', 1), ('bird', 0), ('fish', 6), ('aardvark', 5), ('dog', 1), ('bird', 0), ('fish', 6), ('aardvark', 2), ('egret', 4), ('bird', 0), ('bird', 0), ('bird', 0), ('dog', 5), ('bird', 0), ('aardvark', 1)]}

    test_list_of_lists = []
    for k, v in dict_of_items.items():
        curr_list = []
        for aTuple in v:
            curr_list.append(aTuple[1])
        test_list_of_lists.append(curr_list)

    print(test_list_of_lists)   

main()
```

But that simply merges everything into one list incorrectly: `[[0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 6, 5, 1, 0, 6, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1]]`

I also took a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079472/dot-product-with-dictionaries), but that dictionary is in a much more simple format.

Comment: Why a downvote? I post minimal code, problem, desired results, and what I have attempted?

Comment: I've downvoted because it's not at all clear what operation you want to perform. You call it "dot product", but it's not a dot product. It's not clear how your example output corresponds to your example input; for example, the `('cat', 3)` in `dict_of_items` seems to be completely ignored, as well as most of the `bird` and `dog` values.

Comment: Is multiplying two matrices by each other not a product? If not, please let me know if  I should rephrase to "matrix math" then. `('cat', 3)` in `dict_of_items` appears multiple times, for multiple keys, and would not be completely ignored...however, in key `1`, there is no appearance of `('cat', 3)` so it is ignored. I don't understand your last comment. Only the ***_first_*** example of matrix math / dot product was worked out, where the vector of the search and the first item (`key = 1`) was performed. @user2357112

Comment: Edit - I posted an incorrect dictionary for `dict_of_items`. My apologies. Please see edit @user2357112

Comment: With the corrected dictionary, the question makes more sense.

Comment: Apologies. I was working on the dictionary creation in a larger version of my program and copied the previous, not proper dictionary.

Comment: Do you only need the dot product?

Comment: Ultimately I will be dividing the dot product / the document length (sum of squares for each value in the tuple, grouped by ID, which is the key in `dict_of_items`) for the cosine similarity, but I was going to try and handle that myself. I can add more detail ifyou'd like @DanielMesejo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the doc product of the values on `dict_of_search` vs `dict_of_items`, you could do:

```
def prod(source, target):
    return sum(source.get(key, 0) * target.get(key, 0) for key in source.keys() | target.keys())


dict_of_items = {1: [('dog', 3), ('bird', 0)], 2: [('egret', 2), ('cat', 3), ('bird', 0), ('aardvark', 1)],
                 3: [('fish', 6), ('bird', 0), ('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 5)],
                 4: [('fish', 6), ('bird', 0), ('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 2)], 5: [('egret', 4), ('bird', 0)],
                 6: [('bird', 0)], 7: [('dog', 5), ('bird', 0)], 8: [('bird', 0), ('aardvark', 1)]}

dict_of_search = {1: [('bird', 0), ('dog', 1), ('cat', 3)]}

for k, v in dict_of_items.items():
    for se in dict_of_search.values():
        print(k, prod(dict(v), dict(se)))
```

**Output**

```
1 3
2 9
3 1
4 1
5 0
6 0
7 5
8 0
```

If you want to store the results in a dictionary, do:

```
result = {}
for k, v in dict_of_items.items():
    for se in dict_of_search.values():
        result[k] = prod(dict(v), dict(se))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{1: 3, 2: 9, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 5, 8: 0}
```

Comment: The values look right. How can I capture this in a dictionary, vs just printing values?

Answer (score 0):

it will be easier if you convert your tuples to dictionary like below. then we can use list comprehension like that

```py
dict_of_items = {key:dict(value) for key, value in dict_of_items.items()}
dict_of_search = {key:dict(value) for key, value in dict_of_search.items()}

{item_key: sum([search[key]*item.get(key,0)  for key in search.keys()]) 
     for item_key, item in dict_of_items.items() 
     for search in dict_of_search.values()}
```